# SSRS 2016 Report Subscription running on wrong month

Tags: ssrs-2016

I have an SSRS report subscription with a Report Schedule defined as:-

At 11:45 PM on day(s) 30 of Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov, starting 11/28/2018

Yet it ran on March 30 ...

11:45pm pm on 30th of April, June, September & November Enabled Standard    E-Mail  Mar 30, 2021 11:45:04 PM    Mail sent to ...

Why is this happening?
I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64)   Nov  1 2020 00:13:28   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
On US Pacific time

Thanks

[image: Edit Schedule]

[image: Last Run]

Comment: I've found a reference to someone else having the same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e537d04e-7339-4c19-88ad-e3654ea0670d/ssrs-subscription-misrun?forum=sqlreportingservices